# How to group by columns and merge only the unique strings of another column which are separated by a delimiter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, group-by, merge, duplicates

I have a dataframe of strings columns as shown below

```
id | item  | attributes
------------------------------
1  | apple | fruit, red, round
1  | apple | natural, organic
1  | apple | red
2  | pea   | a green vegetable
2  | pea   | round
```

Notice that an attribute can be a single word or a sentence e.g. `a green vegetable`. If a row has more than one attribute, they are separated by a comma. Now, attribute `red` occurs once in the first row and once in the third row for the same `item` `apple`. Clearly this is a redundancy. The attribute `round` also occurs twice, once in the first row for `apple` and once in fifth row for `pea`. But because `round` occurs for two different items, it is not a redundancy.

For each Item, I want to group by `id` and `item` and merge all the unique attributes into a single cell separated by a comma so that there is no redundancy as shown below:

**Expected output**

```
id | item  | attributes
------------------------------------------------
1  | apple | fruit, red, round, natural, organic
2  | pea   | a green vegetable, round
```

How can I do this in Python? I have tried

```
df['merged'] = df.groupby(['id','item']).attributes.transform(lambda x:", ".join(list(set(x))))
```

But his merges all the attributes and repeats `Red`. How do I merge without repetition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set up data: (I add one more rows to make the sample more representative)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re

df = pd.DataFrame({'item': ['apple']*3+['pea']*3,
                   'atb':['fruit, red, round', 'natural, organic', 'red', 'a green vegetable', 'round', 'dummy, vegetable']})

df
```

Create a self-define function:

```
def string_split(row):
    # empty list:
    counts = list()
    
    # split string by separators: if you want multiple separtors use: | between separators, ex: re.split(' |, |;')
    # this will split by either: (1) ' ', (2) ', ', or (3) ';'
    rowwords = re.split(', ', row)
    
    # obtain unique words:
    for word in rowwords:
        if word not in counts:
            counts.append(word)    
    
    return counts
```

Using `groupby` to combine all rows into one row, separated by `', '`:

```
out = df.groupby('item')['atb'].apply(lambda g: ', '.join(g)).reset_index()
out
```

Using `apply` to get unique words desired:

```
out['new'] = out['atb'].apply(string_split)
out
```