# How to convert cells in a pandas data frame with multiple values to multiple rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am facing an issue while developing a piece of code for the below function. I have a dataframe with the below values

| Date | Name | UserId | task | Client | duration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/2/2022 | 'Alex, J' | 101 | 'C' | QAT | 8 |
| 2/2/2022 | 'Alex, J' | 101 | 'C' | QAT | 8 |
| 1/2/2022 | 'Marc, B' 'Marc, B' | 102 102 | 'A' 'B' | App Dev | 8 |
| 2/2/2022 | 'Marc, B' 'Marc, B' | 102 102 | 'A' 'B' | App Dev | 8 |

Now, I want to convert to the below dataframe.

| Date | Name | UserId | task | Client | duration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/2/2022 | 'Alex, J' | 101 | 'C' | QAT | 8 |
| 2/2/2022 | 'Alex, J' | 101 | 'A' | QAT | 8 |
| 1/2/2022 | 'Marc, B' | 102 | 'A' | App | 4 |
| 1/2/2022 | 'Marc, B' | 102 | 'B' | Dev | 4 |
| 2/2/2022 | 'Marc, B' | 102 | 'A' | App | 4 |
| 2/2/2022 | 'Marc, B' | 102 | 'B' | Dev | 4 |

I want to separate out the values in Name, UserId, task and Client column and want to divide the duration by the number of tasks for a particular day.

For example, I had 2 tasks here i.e A and B for the same day(1/2/2022). So i divided the duration of 8 by 2 and got 4 for each A and B.

I would request you to please help me in this. Thanks alot.

Comment: Warm welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Then update your question to help us to help you. Please create your MWE (minimal working example) with test data like `df = pd.DataFrame(...)`. Beside that look at the `explode()` method in pandas.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @buhtz Apologies for the lapse in format. Thank you for pointing out the correct method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key here is to convert your string in each row to `list` and then use `explode`:

```
# Sample data:
df = pd.DataFrame({'user':['102 102', '103 103'],
                   'task':["'A' 'B'", "'A' 'B'"],
                   'duration':[8, 8]})

# Convert to list 
df['user'] = df['user'].str.split(' ')
df['task'] = df['task'].str.split(' ')

# Split row to multiple rows base on list
df.explode(['user', 'task'])

df
```

If your string is more complicated to separated, consider using `import re`. Or you can view it here: [How to group by columns and merge only the unique strings of another column which are separated by a delimiter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73075125/how-to-group-by-columns-and-merge-only-the-unique-strings-of-another-column-whic/73075698#73075698)

I think the rest is easy and you can do it well

Comment: Thank you so much @PTQuoc for this solution. The code worked like a charm :)